# getCompoundDrawables returns null inside of onCreateView, but not later

Tags: android

I want to run the code below in order to tint a button's drawable on pre-lollipop devices, however button.getCompoundDrawables() is returning null for all 4 elements of the array when called inside of the Fragment's onCreateView method.

If I inspect the same Drawable[] array at a later point in time - say upon a button click event -  I can see the drawable value has been correctly assigned (3 are null, 1 is valid).

Is there some button life cycle or fragment life cycle that I can rely on the compound drawables array to have been already properly initialized?

```
Drawable[] drawables = button.getCompoundDrawables();
        if( drawables[2] != null){
            Drawable wrapDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawables[2]);
            DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapDrawable, color);
            button.invalidate();
        }
```

Here's the lib versions I'm using:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
```

At request, I'm including also some xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
 [...]  >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt1"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:textAppearance="@style/ConfigButtonTheme"
    android:text="Sincronizar Música"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_white_24dp"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How do you initialise `button`?

Comment: @Jay don't mess with version of libraries use same version

Comment: @Shaishav, the button is defined in the layout xml file, so it gets initialized by the framework whenever the view of fragment is initialized.

Comment: Ok..where and how does the `button` variable in your Java code gets initialised?

Comment: @Shaishav: I will share the whole method code below, but please noticed that the button is not null, the problem is that the drawables array has 4 null values inside of it ( it doesn't have the right drawable assigned to it yet):  http://hastebin.com/iyadutejik.avrasm

Comment: Share the method code by editing your question itself so others can easily see it too.

Comment: @Shaishav: I added a link to a pastebin in the previous comment, I dont think it's relevant to the solution :-(

Comment: Please post the whole onCreateView method and layout. Perhaps there is another problem, because it should work.

Comment: @heloisasim, thank you for your feedback, I included some xml code but I'm curious why you say it should work...I just tested in a brand new AppCompatActivity with just the boilerplate code and it still doesnt work (all 4 array elements are null event during the onStart event).

Comment: @Jay in onCreate() it should work because I use this solution. For Activities I use this code inside onCreate() and for Fragments I use inside onCreateView().

Comment: Try to use android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_white_24dp" together with android:drawableEnd.

Comment: @heloisasim it works indeed, I just had to change drawableEnd to drawableRight and it can be accessed on the onCreateMethod... can you add and answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Change `android:drawableEnd` to `android:drawableRight`. Not sure why but drawableEnd returns null in onCreate() method and drawableRight works fine.

Comment: Omg, that's true and I am using API level 26. Thank you

Comment: One note of caution: using drawableRight instead of drawableEnd might interfere with your widget's rendering in locales that have right-to-left writing systems.

Comment: That's weird. Is there a bug for this on Android developers site?

Comment: For rtl support, this is incorrect. See [https://stackoverflow.com/a/47344655/1959110]

Answer (score 58):

for `android:drawableRight`, you should use `getCompoundDrawables()`, where as for `android:drawableEnd`, you should use `getCompoundDrawablesRelative()`.

[getCompoundDrawablesRelative()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getCompoundDrawablesRelative())

Comment: I'm guessing this behavior is for internationalization and support for right-to-left languages. You'd think Google would have the time to document this in the Javadoc, no?

Comment: @jules did you find any other issues as well apart from this when supporting RTL language (using running inspection and supporting internationalization)

Answer (score 0):

You could configure the drawable programmatically and then set it into the text view like so.

```
 val textDrawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_upward_24dp, null)
 val color = ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.colorAccent, null)
     textDrawable.setTint(color)

            //setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(left, top, right, bottom)
     textView.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(null, textDrawable, null, null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `android:drawableEnd` to `android:drawableRight`. Not sure why but `drawableEnd` returns `null` in `onCreate()` method and `drawableRight` works fine.

OR

Another way to do without changing `android:drawableEnd` to `android:drawableRight`.
It will work 100%

just write your code as follow:

```
onCreate(){
    //your all statement
    //at the end
    findViewById(android.R.id.content).post(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
     //write your code here you will get all the drawables
   }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin returns a list of drawables:

```
val drawables = (compoundDrawables zip compoundDrawablesRelative).map {
    it.first ?: it.second
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that the drawable hasn't been created/inflated yet. Try putting that code in either `onActivityCreated`, `onStart` or `onResume` within the Fragment. These are in order of when they will be called within the lifecycle, ideally you want to do this as soon as possible.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I had already tried it during onStart, but it's still null at that point. I used this fragment lifecycle chart to find out the latest point in time I could hook the code up:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/fRxIQ.png

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't load your drawables within TextView at the beginning. You should use

```
TextView.post({ 
    // get your drawables here.
})
```

this function to get your drawables when it's loaded.